# Rails 3 - paperclip with perloader

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, paperclip, image-preloader

I use for upload my images `Paperclip`. I would like to ask you, if exist any gem or plugin for showing the preloader while the image is uploading (something like "56% loaded").

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't have to do anything with paperclip actually.

I am using mootools, with [mootools](http://mootools.net/) I am using [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) which has lots of options and is very well written and easy to debug, rewrite, extend etc...

When you use this, you get an "Ajax" upload with a progress bar.

if you are using jQuery, there are many plugins for that as well.
it's very easy to integrate into the project.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am trying to find some tutorial with jQuery, but unfortunately I can't find something useful...